# Intermittent issue with Telerik TabStrip controls 'error creating control'

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I've been getting an intermittent issue when i'm adding or using the telerik controls for tabstrip.

Here's what it looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQX54.jpg

error creating control - telerik:RadTabStrip Duplicate component name 'RadTabStrip1'. Component names must be unique and case-insensitive.

What i've done:

Restarted VS
Uninstalled and reinstalled AJAX controls
Copied the Telerik.Web.UI bin file to my project's bin directory
All assemblies in web.config matches the current version of BIN i'm working on.

However, i'm still getting this issue more frequent than usual. It works again after clicking on the smart tag a couple of times or after restarting VS. recently, i had to keep on updating the BIN files and restart VS again to make it work. Also tried to clear VS cache but it keeps on happening. You guys have other suggestion on how i can permanently resolve this issue?

Update:

It happened again and seems to happen when try to follow the hierarchy w templates demo and do the following

1. Created a grid and included a nestedviewtemplate tag
2. made a radtabstrip inside the tag
3. placed one tab and added a multi page (used the smart tags at this point)
4. added a radlistview control. even added the placeholder tag.
5. Here's what i made after the  tag

```html
<telerik:RadMultiPage ID="RadMultiPage1" runat="server">
  <telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageView1" runat="server">
    <telerik:RadListView ID="RadListView1" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="PlaceHolder1" DataKeyNames="JobOrderIndex" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource20">
      <LayoutTemplate>
        <div>
          <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </div>
      </LayoutTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><i>Job Order No.</i>
            </td>
            <td>
              <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("JobOrderNumber", "{0}") %>'></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>
              <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("JobOrderStatus", "{0}") %>'></asp:Label>
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Plate Number</td>
            <td>
              <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProfitCenter", "{0}") %>'></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>Job Type</td>
            <td>
              <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("JobType", "{0}") %>'></asp:Label>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Job Order Date</td>
            <td>
              <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("JobOrderDate", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>Created By</td>
            <td>
              <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Problem Description</td>
            <td colspan="3">
              <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProblemDescription", "{0}") %>'></asp:Label>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </telerik:RadListView>
```

So, i noticed that the error occurs as soon as i place the source for the RadListView control and certain other controls or smart tags for the grid or the tab will not show up.

If you notice that i'm not doing anything right (which is most of the time) please let me know and i would appreciate the wisdom you can share with me so it can be the Telerik master race i ought to be.

Thanks again,

C

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I eventually added a control .aspx page and this error occurs when 2 controls with the same ID is found in one module.